onsubmit event not working if in the form is a input with confirm name
onsubmit event not working if in the form is a input with confirm name or id .
if i add below input to the form the onsubmit event not working
  <input type="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm">



<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure ?')">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>



when i removed the input with confirm name the onsubmit event work!!!
it is very strange and unusual.

What is your question specifically? How to make it work or why it's not working?

its very strang and unusual for me why i have a input with confirm name the event not working!!! is it a BUG  in JS or HTML?

See Do DOM tree elements with IDs become global properties? - the field ID confirm makes the browser point the global variable confirm to this field, therefor overwriting the confirm method of the window object.

no, it is not a bug, giving id="confirm" will override window.confirm() method.

It's not id alone, it's the name attribute confirm in the form (this binding in inline listeners is done using with).

And you don't need to use and id on on form's.elements to access them...

otherwise you can use onsubmit="return window.confirm('Are you sure ?')" instead...

@CBroe That was my initial thought too, but that's not what's happening here. confirm on window isn't overwritten, it's more just that confirm from the form element is accessible directly within the scope of the onsubmit attribute, and so that's being accessed, window.confirm remains as is though.

@NickParsons yeah, you're right. The confirm in the "scope" of the form gets found when JS tries to resolve that identifier; if that wasn't there, it would go "up the tree" to find confirm in the global object

Your issue is that the scope of onXYZ attribute handlers (DOM level 0 handlers) is "augmented" in a way that adds the form's identifiers to the scope of your script specified in the attribute, and so confirm ends up referring to your input element, not the browser's confirm method (window.confirm).
To do this, the browser creates an ad-hoc function and puts the content of your attribute into this function (return confirm('Are you sure ?')), which gets executed when the event (in your case onsubmit) is fired, however, most browsers will change the scope chain of this function so that it's populated with properties from the document, the form and the current element. So your onsubmit code is wrapped in a function more or less that looks like this (see reference):
function onsubmit(event) {
  with (document) {
    with (this.form) { // in your case `undefined` (not applicable in this scenario, but good to know for when you add `onXYZ` attributes to input elements inside a form for example)
      with (this) { // in your case, `this` is the form element (and has properties like the `confirm` and `name` inputs)
        return confirm('Are you sure ?') // contents of your onsubmit attribute is inserted into here (here `confirm` refers to the input element, not the browsers confirm method due to the with-block above)
      }
    }
  }
}

Since the scope of your onsubmit method is modified to have bindings for the properties of your form, accessing confirm (or name) accesses the DOM input elements, not the global confirm method. The easiest fix for this is to access window.confirm, or change your form name and id so it doesn't conflict with a global:


<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return window.confirm('Are you sure ?')">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>



But the more appropriate fix would be to avoid using DOM level 0 attribute event handlers, and instead, use addEventListener() with e.preventDefault() to stop the form from submitting.


const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  if(!confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
<form action="/" method="post" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>




The issue occurs because the confirm() function in your onsubmit event is being overridden by the confirm input element. When you have an element with an id, it creates a global variable with that name, which can interfere with built-in JavaScript functions.
To fix this, you have a few options:

Change the name and id of the checkbox:



<!-- 
Online HTML, CSS and JavaScript editor to run code online.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Browser</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure ?')">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="agreement">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</body>

</html>




Use a different function name for the confirmation:



<!-- 
Online HTML, CSS and JavaScript editor to run code online.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Browser</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return confirmSubmission()">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function confirmSubmission() {
  return confirm('Are you sure ?');
}
</script>
</body>

</html>




Use addEventListener instead of the inline onsubmit attribute:



<!-- 
Online HTML, CSS and JavaScript editor to run code online.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Browser</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/" method="post" id="myForm">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            if (!confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>



Any of these solutions should resolve the issue and allow your form submission confirmation to work properly.
